# Turning off main keys in a laptop

Tags: key

Okay so basically, I want to turn off the sleep and airplane mode keys. I always press them accidentally and it really ruins what I'm doing. however, I have no idea how to do that; the keys are:

Sleep Mode: F1
Airplane Mode: F2
*I use a Windows 10

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Windows? Linux? Mac? BeOS?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. Windows 10.